# Cannot get the basic socket.io example to work on client

Tags: node.js

I installed Node on my Windows server using the .msi package that can be downloaded at the nodejs.org website, and it's running fine.  Then I ran `npm install socket.io` and that went fine, too.  It installed socket.io to `C:\node_modules\socket.io`.  I added the example server code found on the socket.io website into a new file called `app.js`.  The only change I made was the port number to 1337.  I then started Node with app.js like so:  `node app.js` into the command line, and got the `info: socket.io started` message.

On the clientside--my OSX laptop where I'm developing my web app--I'm not sure how to properly get the `socket.io.js` file and all its dependencies so I can include it in my HTML page's `<script>` tag.  From the `How do I serve the client` FAQ page on the socket.io Wiki:

> The client is served automatically by the Node.JS server. In your  tag of your HTML, include:

```
<script src="http://<uri:port>/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

So, I  added this to my index.html page:

```
<script src="http://my.windows.server.domain.com:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

When I upload my index.html file to my webserver, and point my browser to it, I check the console and find:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/1/?t=1330983853883. Origin http://my.web.server.domain.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`
```

Has anybody encountered this message with socket.io?  Any tips as to how I can get the client to include the code it needs so I can begin using the awesomeness that socket.io is?

Answer (score 1):

This is because normally XHR cannot be cross-domain (and the initial "handshake" goes through XHR before raising to socket.io protocol). Did you do something with default socket.io settings? Try adding this:

```
io.set("origins","*");
```

in your socket.io server settings. If this does not work, then maybe you use old version of socket.io? I think 0.9 is current.

Comment: No, didn't touch the default socket.io server settings.  However, from the example code for index.html on the socket.io website, it has this line: `var socket = io.connect('localhost');`, so I realized that my socket.io server is not the same as my webserver as the example assumes.  I changed `io.connect('localhost');` to `io.connect('http://my.windows.server.domain.com:1337');` and it's working now.

Comment: Oh, I assumed that you entered the correct domain in `io.connect()`. :) I'm glad it works for you now. Good luck with NodeJS and socket.io!